# Batch File To Convert All Files In Directory To ATF

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am currently developing and Adobe Air mobile application and need to convert a large number of files from .png to .atf.

I currently do this by running commands like the one below on every file.

```
png2atf -c d -r -q 0 -f 0 -i inputFile.png -o outputFile.atf
```

I've created a batch file and added the commands line by line ...it works but I have to update that every time a file name changes.
I've tried a couple of loops I've found around the web ...but haven't managed to get it working.
I would really appreciated if some one can help me out with a piece of code that would loop
through the files/directories in a the input folder and recreate the structure in an output directory while converting the files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to create for `Pic001.png` the file new converted file `Pic001.atf` with the same *basename* but different extension.

Try something like

```
 for %%f in (*.png) do (
          png2atf -c d -r -q 0 -f 0 -i "%%~nf.png" -o "%%~nf.atf"     
 )
```

Complete by yourself adding the name of the directories of origin and destination.
You can select all the files and not only the png ones changing `(*.png)` in `(*.*)`.

Comment: Thanks. Giving it a try later today. Any idea how I would go about recreating the directory structure also. My source directory has several child directories that contain PNGs. Going to try adding a loop for every child dir for now...